# Dragging list item to replace it styles all other items (react-js)

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, antd

I'm working on a ReactJS application and I've used the "ListSort-AntMotion" (https://motion.ant.design/exhibition/demo/list-sort) component to make my list items sortable. However, when I try to drag one list item to replace it, it seems that the styles are added to all the other list items.

I've created a CodeSandbox to demonstrate the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/sortable-list-sjgktq?file=/src/ListSort.js

If you compare the demos, you can see the difference in dragging an item. How can I resolve this issue?